# CodeIgniter Session variables not passing

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I am using native PHP sessions ($_SESSION) with CodeIgniter framework.

I have a "Login" controller loads view where user enters login and password. 
After the user submits the login form, the  "Login" controllers authenticate() method is called. 
If everything is alright i add some data to $_SESSION array, then i redirect user to "Organisation" controllers myOrganisation() method. 
I'm calling session_start() in Login/login() , Login/authenticate() and Organisation/myOrganisation() methods, but still the session is not passed, because in myOrganisation() method the session is new.

I tested my cookies functionality with creating 2 test php pages, where i just echo session id. It works perfectly.
Maybe i am not putting session_start() in all places it needs to be? (i put them in all controllers methods).

Login Controller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
        session_start();
        $this->load->view("Login/index", $data);

    public function authenticate() {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['login'] = $login; //  everything is alright, redirect
        header("location: ".base_url()."Organisations/MyOrganisation");
```

Organisation controller:

```
public function MyOrganisation() {
    session_start(); // here session is a new one, not passed
    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
```

Comment: Does base_url() return the same domain as where you login? Otherwise your session would restart.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you are not using the CodeIgniter built in Session Library? Also, this might just be a product of you typing it in here, but you haven't closed your first function. index() is still open when you start authenticate().

Comment: in src, index() is closed. I am not using CI sessions because i got some problems, trying to configure and make them work. Spent like 4 hours, and they never worked, so i decided to switch to native seesions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was wrong with the session_start() placements that i did, but the one thing that solved the problem was to place it in index.php in main folder

Comment: that solved the problem for me too. I asked a similar question, but I thought the issue was different because I am using CodeIgniter with a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

session_start() can also be specified in a constructor, not every method in a class. That means both your controllers can have this:

```
function __construct () {
    ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 14400);
    ini_set("session.cookie_domain", .yourdomain.com);
    session_set_cookie_params(14400, '/', .yourdomain.com);
    session_start();
}
```

The first 3 lines in a constructor are to make sure the session cookie is valid for a long time and under you domain.

Besides that (and not closed index() and authenticate() methods), where's $login coming from?

Comment: i just omitted the most part of code, which was not important